# upload photo on google cloud server

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

I want to upload the photo in google cloud server instead of my server to avoid load on my sever. Also I want to fetch the images later in my server. I will do that in php and mysql. Is it possible to do that? If so then how shall I proceed? Please help me.

Comment: What google cloud servers? App Engine?

Comment: Actually what I need, I want photo will be uploaded some another server like google cloud storage, which will be secure, also I can able to fetch the photos whenever need.

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with Google Cloud Storage via its [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/developer-guide)  or use a php library like [tws_service_google_storage](https://github.com/dragonmantank/tws_service_google_storage).